# EF Code First comparing null values generates strange query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I´m trying to list some categories (parent child relationship) and I have the following command to list only parent categories

```
context.Categories.Where(c => c.ParentId == null)
```

But the sql query generated by EF does not return anything

sql query generated by EF

```
SELECT 
CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C1], 
CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) AS [C2], 
CAST(NULL AS bit) AS [C3], 
CAST(NULL AS int) AS [C4]
FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]
WHERE 1 = 0
```

category model

```
public class Category
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public bool IsActive { get; set; }
  public virtual IList<Category> SubCategories { get; set; }
  internal int? ParentId { get; set; }
  public virtual Category Parent { get; set; }

  public override bool Equals(object obj)
  {
    var categoryToCompare = obj as Category;
    if (categoryToCompare == null) return false;

    return categoryToCompare.Id == Id;
  }

  public override int GetHashCode()
  {
    return Id.GetHashCode();
  }
}
```

Mapping

```
public class CategoryConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Category>
{
  public CategoryConfiguration()
  {
    ToTable("tbl_category");
    HasKey(c => c.Id);
    Property(c => c.Id).HasColumnName("cd_category");
    Property(c => c.Name).HasColumnName("ds_category");
    Property(c => c.IsActive).HasColumnName("fl_active");
    Property(c => c.ParentId).HasColumnName("cd_base_category").IsOptional();
    HasMany(c => c.SubCategories).WithRequired(c => c.Parent).HasForeignKey(c => c.ParentId);
  }
}
```

Comment: @caerolus yes EF generated that

Comment: Use `(c => !c.ParentId.HasValue)`

Comment: @Fendy generates the same query

Comment: Is there *nothing* more to your query that you aren't showing us? I had EF generate the same sort of SQL once, and it turned out, I had some invalid inputs to fix.

Comment: See related blog post here: http://colinmackay.co.uk/2011/07/30/entity-framework-query-that-never-brings-back-data/

Comment: @AnthonyPegram is just that

Comment: The relationship is on the same table, is possible that is causing the problem?

Comment: Added mapping configuration

Comment: Why is ParentId internal? EF needs to be able to access this property

Comment: Even as public I got the same query result

Comment: I would strongly recommend leaving it as public regardless of weather is solves your current problem

Comment: @LukeMcGregor - EF should be able to access properties regardless of their visibility...

Comment: @MarcioToshio - I believe what you see is because EF know there will be no results from your query and does this trick to have an empty result sets whose shape is corresponding to the entity you are asking about. Having said that - I wanted to understand why this happens and I don't see the ParentId property being mapped altogether (I used EdmxWriter to dump your model) and when trying to do `ctx.Categories.Where(c => c.ParentId == null).ToString();` -> I see NotSupportedException: The specified type member 'ParentId' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, ...

Comment: The mapping is somehow strange because it defines `Parent` as required while FK property is nullable.

Comment: @LadislavMrnka this make sense EF see the property as required and I trying to query some nullable value so EF generates this query that is explained on the link that RAS pointed. Now I cannot test the code when is possible i will do the test

Comment: @LadislavMrnka tks to point that now it's working

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting this as an answer because **surely** one of these will work:

Your `ParentId` property needs to be `public virtual` -  try changing that first.

Then, try `context.Categories.Where(c => !c.ParentId.HasValue)`

Then, try `context.Categories.Where(c => c.Parent == null)`

I have applications where the above works fine.

Then, try `context.Categories.Where(c => object.Equals(c.Parent, null))`

That last one is a [bit of a hack from someone at MS](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/d00f5611-4fce-4da4-8f79-802336fdfe1a#42146558-3e0b-4fd6-a11b-6855881f9724), but apparently should work.